# google apps script jquery hover not working

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I'm working with GAS HTML service and jquery.

I want to show some edit buttons when the mouse is hover a certain row of a table.
The problem is that the hover function of jquery is not working.

I tried with several elements such as tr,td, even li, with no success.
I don't know if it is a caja problem or what.

Could you help me?

> EDIT
>   I think I found the problem: due to caja I can't bind functions to elements dinamically.
>   I put the binding operations inside the ready function and it now works well.
>   I don't understand the mechanism very well, so if somebody can explain it to me I will be very grateful.
>   Why the document ready function is not considered as dinamically? Why that function works an others will not?

Here is the HTML code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.odd {background: #d3d3d3;}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabs").tabs();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillTabs).getAllTabsData();
}); 

$("tr").hover(
  function () {
   console.log("Mouse hover row");
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
  }, 
  function () {
  console.log("Mouse leaving row");
    $(this).css("background","");
  }
);

$( "li.fade" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
  $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
</div>

<script>

function fillTabs(tabs) {
  var tabsDiv;//=$('#tabs');
  var table;
  var data;
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {

    data=tabs[i].data;
    var tabName=tabs[i].name;
    tabsDiv=$('#'+tabName);
    table='<table>'

    for( var j=0; j<data.length; j++){
      table+='<tr>'
      for(var k=0; k<data[j].length;k++){
        table+='<td>'+data[j][k]+'</td>'
      }
      table+='</tr>'
    }
    table+='</table/>'

    tabsDiv.html(table);
  }
  $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
  $("#tabs").tabs();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Since elements are dynamically generated, you have to use events as a delegate method ie. `$(document).on()` and you cant use `hover` as a delegate method, Hover is the combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, The code is below

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','tr',function()
{
console.log("Mouse hover row");
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','tr',function()
{
console.log("Mouse leaving row");
    $(this).css("background","");
});
```

### Answer for Edit

`$(document).ready()` will be loaded first at the page load time , However at that time newly generated elements are not there, so binding an event to that will not work. Therefore as delegate methods are used, it represent the dynamically generated element.

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I said on my edit, If I place the binding inside the $(document).ready() function, it works as expected. I don't know if this could generate any problem. Is your code better? I mean, Is it more standards compilant? What do you mean with delegate method? Is possible in your code to use hover instead of mouseenter and mouseleave? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Danielo515, Your code worked because you were generating the elements on $(document).ready(), but if it like you are creating elemnts up on button click , your code wont work.

Comment: Your code works like a charm. I accepted it as correct answer. I though the problem was due to GAS caja, but now I see the problem is the dynamically generated elements. Your code will work also with class and ID selectors? As you said, I did not take in account newly generated elements without refreshing the whole page. Where can I find the reference for other events using this kind of binding?

Comment: @Danielo515, just refer this for basic http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_type.asp